# In memory links or hidden properties to a node

Tags: neo4j, in-memory

Are in memory links or hidden properties to a node possible in Neo4j or using it's related languages(Cypher, Gremlin etc.,)?

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can come to in-memory relationships is to begin a transaction, create the relationships, do your query and then roll back the transaction. However that imposes a write lock on the start and end nodes of the relationships you are creating.